# Crear links para referidos usando python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Como podría darle a los usuarios un link propio por el que puedan obtener referidos usando python-telegram-bot, ósea cuando una persona entra al bot usando uno de esos link, el programa podría identificar a cual usuario pertenece el link de referencia y poderle dar una recompensa

Un ejemplo configuro un mensaje donde el usuario puede obtener su link de referencia

```
def enviarMensajeConElLinkDeReferencia(update,ctx):
    link="esto es lo que no encuentro como"
    update.message.reply_text("Su link propio es"+str(link))
```

La respuesta a esta pregunta sería solo el método de la api de python-telegram-bot que retorne o al menos permita crearle un link a los usuarios

Intente por la vía de tal ves crear sus link con

```
update.effective_message.chat.export_invite_link()
```

y

```
update.effective_message.chat.create_invite_link()
```

pero  me salta el error

```
telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't invite members to a private chat
```

supongo que es porque estos últimos métodos son solo para ‘supergrups’ mientras que el dialogo es privado, entonces existirá algún método que me retorne un link único de cada usuario? Que funcione en sus respectivos chat privados

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] porque tu pregunta tal cual está no es válida y acabará cerrada. Para más info puedes consultar [help]. Así a grandes rasgos, aquí ayudamos con errores de programación... tú solo nos has contado lo que necesitas y dado que no trabajamos para ti, eso no tiene mucho sentido aquí :) Te recomiendo que si quieres hacerlo, lo hagas (o al menos lo intentes). Cualquier *error concreto que tengas* seguro que le podemos encontrar solución aquí :)

Comment: Ya la edite, no sé si será más correcta así, gracias por su consejo

Answer (score 0):

En teoría cualquier link de la forma https://t.me/Tu_Bot?nombreComando=valorArgumento te redirigiría a tu bot , pero lo que necesitas es uno que funcione con el comando start ( comienzo del bot )y de alguna forma puedas acceder a la información  del que identifique de forma única al patrocinador

Entonces para ello utilizaremos como identificador único al id que provee telegram a cada usuario y como comando al start que se ejecuta solo al principio (aunque si un usuario usa el link de referencia varias veces se ejecutaría esa cantidad de veces por lo que si la acción de patrocinio es única, tienes que crear algo que impida que tu código de acción, tal ves recompensa, se ejecute más de una vez, como almacenar en una bd la información de que ya fue utilizado tal link de referencia por tal usuario )

La api nos provee de un método que nos devuelve una url de referencia con un argumento que decidamos pasarle, en este caso el id

Te lo muestro aquí en este ejemplo:

```
from telegram.utils import helpers
def enviarMensajeConElLinkDeReferencia(update,context):
    bot = context.bot
    user = update.effective_message.from_user
    link=helpers.create_deep_linked_url(bot.username, str(user.id))
    #Link de referencia de la forma: https://t.me/Tu_Bot?start=XXXXXXXXXX
    update.message.reply_text("Su link propio es"+str(link))
```

Luego tenemos que reaccionar a la entrada del usario en el bot usando el link y reconocer el id pasado

Para ello se usa un filtro regex, tomando en cuenta que el id son 10 números seguidos, que se le pasa a al CommandHandler para el comando start

Y en su función de evento se acceden a los argumentos de context , en donde en este caso solo abra uno, el id que necesitamos

Te muestro un código de ejemplo

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters

#... Se instancia el updater y el dispatcher

def accionEnStart(update,context):
    idUsuarioDeTelegramDePatrocinador=context.args[0]
    update.message.reply_text("Tu patrocinador es " + str(idUsuarioDeTelegramDePatrocinador))


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", accionEnStart, Filters.regex("([0-9]{10})")))
```

Me base en el artículo que se encuentra en:

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples/#deeplinkingpy

Comment: intente marcar tu respuesta como correcta pero como ahora fue que termine de crear la cuenta parece ser que la plataforma perdió el registro de que fui yo quien formulo la pregunta, no se como te afecte eso , CodeMas